# Iterate through Django list and display unique Django-Taggit tags only

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I would like to list all the tags from Django-Taggit only if they are being used in an object and only when they pertain to a particular model. For example; I have a page that lists parts and a page that lists tool.  I am tagging everything, but on my home page, I would like to display the tool tags and the part tags in separate columns.

The code below will show all tags, even the ones unused and from all models.  The code below is what I am working with currently and I know why its doing this, but I am not sure how to filter out `if` the object has a tag and `if` it belongs to the tool or part model, which is why I have a tool `for` loop wrapping it, but this seems wrong. Thank you for your help.

**view**

```
def main_index(request):
    tools = Tool.objects.prefetch_related('uploads').all().order_by('title')
    tags = Tag.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'tools': tools, 'tags': tags})
```

**template**

```
{% for t in tools %}
  {% for tag in tags.all %}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div class="c-content-feature-2" data-wow-delay1="1s" data-height="height">
         <h5 class="c-font-uppercase c-center"><a href="{% url "products:tool_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a></h5>
       </div>
   </div>
  {% if not forloop.last %} {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what does *if they are being used in an object* mean?

Comment: If I add a tag to a tool it exists if I don't it doesn't. Sorry for the confusion, I was probably mixing up my explanation with things I've tried.  If I iterate over Tool.objects, I want to display all the tags that are found, but not list duplicate tags, just the unique ones.  With the tags on my home page -  when a user clicks on the tag.name, they will go to the tool_list page and see all the tools with just that tag.  Does this make better sense?  Thank you.

Comment: is this correct: {% for tag in tags.all %} you have already called Tag.objects.all() in your view

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, I figured it out and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with it and pulling my hair out; I was able to iterate over my queryset, then filter out the tag names using [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). My new code is below - this seems to be a clean way of doing the job and I can find other uses for it.  Thank you for taking the time to try and help.

**views**

```
def main_index(request, tag_slug=None):
    tools = Tool.objects.prefetch_related('uploads').distinct('tags')
    parts = Part.objects.prefetch_related('uploads').distinct('tags')
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        tools = Tool.objects.filter(tags__in=[tag])
        parts = Part.objects.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'tools': tools, 'parts': parts, 'tag': tag})
```

**template**

```
{% for t in tools %}
  {% for tag in t.tags.all %}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="c-content-feature-2" data-wow-delay1="1s" data-height="height">
        <h5 class="c-font-uppercase c-center"><a href="{% url "products:tool_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% if not forloop.last %} {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will work but there are lots of queries in it. You are querying parts but not using it at all?

Comment: Are you talking about the parts query?  If so, I have the same thing in my template for parts, just not showing it able.  I am going to add pics or the tags, which is the uploads part of it, just not showing that either.  If you are talking about something else, please elaborate on your comment; I am still learning and need to use opportunities like this to get better. Thank you.

Comment: ok if you are using it elsewhwere in your template that solves part of it. Howeever if you look closely at your view, don't oyu think your first two queries should actually be in an else to avoid running them unnecessarily

Comment: Now that I look at it, you are probably right.  I will try that changes in the morning and let you know.  Thanks.